# JavaScript - can't make the timer function to be called when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make my simple timer function to be called when the page is loaded. But it doesn't work. I think I made mistake somewhere in the `if else` loop, maby here: `setTimeout(function(tag, sec), 1000);`
How can I fix it?

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(tag, sec) {
 tag = "timerPlace";
 sec = 3600;
  
    document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML = "<div id= 'inTime'>" + (sec / 60 >> 0) + 'min ' + sec % 60 + 'sec' + '<br>' + "</div>";



    if ((sec / 60 >> 0) != 0 || (sec % 60) != 0) {
      setTimeout(function(tag, sec), 1000);
      sec -= 1;
    } else {
      document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML = "Time is over!";
    }
  
  }, false);
</script>

<div id="timerPlace"></div>
```

Comment: First thing, syntax of your `setTimeout` line is incorrect. It should be something like, `setTimeout(functionName, 1000, argument1, argument2 )`. After that, do you really want to call the function that fires on `DOMContentLoaded` again in `setTimeout`?

Comment: There is an error in your code and some bad practices. You are missing the callback for the setTimeout `setTimeout(function(tag, sec) {// CODE }, 1000);

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Is there another simple way to make the function starts after the page is loaded?

Comment: @andybeli what would be a good practice for making a function to be called when the page is loaded?

Comment: Are you willing to use jQuery for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

javascript

```
// Code goes here
function saysomething() {
    alert('say something');

}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(tag, sec) {


    tag = "timerPlace";
    sec = 3600;

    document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML = "<div id= 'inTime'>" + (sec / 60 >> 0) + 'min ' + sec % 60 + 'sec' + '<br>' + "</div>";




    if ((sec / 60 >> 0) != 0 || (sec % 60) != 0) {
        // setTimeout(function(tag, sec), 1000);
        setTimeout(saysomething, 1000);
        sec -= 1;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML = "Time is over!";
    }

}, false);
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="timerPlace"></div>
</body>
```

or

```
<script>
  //Timer function
 window.onload = function() {
  myFunction();

}; 


  function myFunction(){

   timer('timerPlace',3600);
  }

  function timer(tag, sec) {
    document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML = "<div id= 'inTime'>" +
      (sec / 60 >> 0) + 'min ' + sec % 60 + 'sec' + '<br>' + "</div>";



    if ((sec / 60 >> 0) != 0 || (sec % 60) != 0) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        timer(tag, sec);
      }, 1000);
      sec -= 1;
    } else {
      document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML = "Time is over!";
    }
  }
</script>

<div id="timerPlace"></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<!-- Write number of seconds here: onclick="timer('str',...here!...)  -->

<button class="button" onclick="timer('timerPlace',3600); style.display = 'none'"> <span>Start Test</span> 
</button>

<!-- Place this div where you whant timer to be. -->
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need, but I need it to continue writing time and decrementing sec value (this way my timer works). Here is an original code of the timer function, that I want to be called after the page is loaded (without clicking a bitton). https://jsfiddle.net/MaximVelichkin/c0s9bkLa/

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your code. I still don't really know what you are trying to achieve.
setTimeout callback is empty for you to write what it needs to do.
This is the correct way to wait for the DOM to be ready before executing a query looking for an element in it.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
    var tag = "timerPlace";
    var sec = 3600;
    document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML = "<div id= 'inTime'>" + (sec / 60 >> 0) + 'min ' + sec % 60 + 'sec' + '<br>' + "</div>";

    if ((sec / 60 >> 0) != 0 || (sec % 60) != 0) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        //Do something after 1000
      }, 1000);
      sec -= 1;
    } else {
      document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML = "Time is over!";
    }

});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98wegkow/)

Edit:

To execute after page load, use this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  //Code to execute after page load
});
```

Comment: This is a simple timer function, but i faced problems trying to make it be called when the page is loaded. Here is the original code https://jsfiddle.net/MaximVelichkin/c0s9bkLa/

Comment: callback should do the same - write the time and then decrement sec value.

Comment: I edited my answer... `window.addEventListener('load', function () {`

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/Lk963xa0/

Made an example with Jquery, not sure if this is what you are looking for

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 tag = "timerPlace";
 sec = 15;

 var timer = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
    sec--;
    document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML = "<div id= 'inTime'>" + sec + "</div>"
    if(sec === 0 ){console.log("time is out"); return}
    timer();
  }, 1000);
 };

 timer();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="timerPlace"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I need pure JS without JQuery.

Comment: Okey, just replace $(document).ready() with document.addEventListener() then :)

Comment: jQuery ready method waits for the DOM to be ready not the whole page load. So it would be the same as what I previously wrote.